# How to deploy the contextual gadgets in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm trying to deploy my "hello world" gadget in Gmail. I'm checking this link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

these are the steps:

Log into the console.
Do one of the following:
Create a project.
Select an existing project in the Project dropdown.
Upload your application manifest.
Deploy your application.

When I create my project I can not find any option to upload my manifest. Can anyone help me?

Thank you